# Restrict docker container internet access

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, iptables

**TLDR;** - Added some iptable rules to a docker container to limit internet access. Working fine except that now I am unable to access container app from host machine but can do so from within container itself

I have a container running a webapp. This container uses `mysql`, `redis` etc. Every dependency are remote, accessible by an ip address, on a particular port.

So, for instance, mysql is accessible on ip 13.255.255.255

What I want is to allow the container only to be able to use mysql ip address and not any other. There are few `curl` requests originating from within the code which I do not want to go beyond my host machine's network.

I've added an entrypoint script in docker which adds some `iptables` rule in container.

```sh
ALLOWED_CIDR1=172.0.0.0/16
ALLOWED_CIDR2=13.255.255.255 #For mysql access

#iptables -P FORWARD DROP # we aren't a router
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP # Drop everything we don't accept

iptables -A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s ::1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d ::1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $ALLOWED_CIDR1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $ALLOWED_CIDR1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ALLOWED_CIDR2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ALLOWED_CIDR2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

When I run container and do

`docker-compose exec <container-name> curl http://google.com`

I get following in response:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com

which is expected. Now, when I do

`docker-compose exec <container-name> curl http://0.0.0.0`

I get following response:

> "Hello World!"

Which again is expected. However, when I do `curl http://0.0.0.0` from my host machine, following is the output

```
* Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 0.0.0.0
> User-Agent: curl/7.62.0
> Accept: */*
> // Hangs here
```

So, I am unable to connect to http://0.0.0.0 from host machine, but can connect from inside the docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am utterly stupid to overlook the iptables rules I posted myself.

*Wrong set of rules*

```
ALLOWED_CIDR1=172.0.0.0/16
ALLOWED_CIDR2=13.255.255.255 #For mysql access

#iptables -P FORWARD DROP # we aren't a router
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP # Drop everything we don't accept

iptables -A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s ::1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d ::1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $ALLOWED_CIDR1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $ALLOWED_CIDR1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ALLOWED_CIDR2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ALLOWED_CIDR2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

You can see, in the above section:

1. There is no **OUTPUT ACCEPT** for ip 0.0.0.0
2. There is no **OUTPUT ACCEPT** rule for ip `192.168.x.x` which is the ip address of my `docker-0` network interface

Both docker and host machine communicates using the `docker0` network interface if network mode `bridged` is used while launching container (which happened to be my case).

Another thing I noticed, I didn't required the `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1` rules at all. Since the entrypoint script will add the iptable rules within docker container, we may never want to access webapp from within container itself. Hence, why bother with 127.0.0.1?

All in all, here is what I did:

1. Get my ip address for `docker0` network. `ip addr show docker0`. It outputted 192.168.144.1/20
2. I added 192.168.0.0/16 to **ACCEPT** rules in my entrypoint iptable rules, which covered my ipaddress in point 1
3. Now I can access my container from outside

My iptable rules looks like this now:

```
ALLOWED_CIDR1=172.0.0.0/16
ALLOWED_CIDR2=13.255.255.255
ALLOWED_CIDR3=192.168.0.0/16

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP # Drop everything we don't accept
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -s $ALLOWED_CIDR1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $ALLOWED_CIDR2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $ALLOWED_CIDR3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ALLOWED_CIDR1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ALLOWED_CIDR2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ALLOWED_CIDR3 -j ACCEPT
```